# CSS Card with fixed height and responsive image

Tags: css, vue.js

I have a file input with preview.

This is the pen [Codepen](https://codepen.io/robypez/pen/dLQGbb)

I want to force the height and I cannot understand how can I do.
I want to fix the height of this component to 300px (example) and I need also to keep the right aspect ratio of the image loaded, filling the gaps with a grey background. Now I keep the aspect ratio, but the height change according to the image loaded.

This is my HTML (it's a vue component)

```
  <body><div id="">
  <div class="field-body row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card" style="height: 400px">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image imup-image" style="padding-top: 75%">

          <img src="http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/img/gamma-test-2.png">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <footer class="card-footer">
        <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" >Elimina</button>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-file">



                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

      </footer>
    </div>

  </div></div></div>

</body>
```

And this is the CSS

```
figure {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #acacac;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .custom-file-label::after {
    background-color: #375faf;
    color: white;
  }
  .btn {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .imup-image {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .alert{
    position:absolute; /*it can be fixed too*/
    left:0; right:0;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:50px;
    z-index: 3;
    /*this to solve "the content will not be cut when the window is smaller than the content": */
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
  }
  img {
  /* make the image inside the padding space */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    /* make sure the image will not over the division */
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    /* center the image */
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

You can try with the component, it works, it keep the image aspect ration. But I need to force the height.

Comment: Instead of the Vue source HTML share the resulting output HTML. Currently cannot reproduce with this code alone.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo I removed Vue, now is plain html and css.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `object-fit` & `object-position` css rules for your figure? Looks like it could fix your problem.

Comment: On the figure tag?

Comment: On `img` tag, my typo

Comment: I need to fix the height of the card. I cannot fix the height